# How to create a static pointer to a vector in C++?

Tags: c++, static

How can I create a static pointer to a vector in C++. I've tried

```
// myfile.cpp
struct MyStruct
{
    static int x;
    static vector<int> *vec;
};

int MyStruct::x = 0;
vector<int> MyStruct::*vec = NULL;

int myfunc(vector<int> *nvec)
{
    static MyStruct *ms = NULL;
    if (ms == NULL)
    {
        ms->x = 7;
        ms->vec = nvec;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But I just get `undefined reference to MyStruct::vec`

`MyStruct::x` works fine though. What's up with the vector?

Comment: Unrelated, but consider using `nullptr` instead of the `NULL` macro

Comment: if `ms == NULL` then doing `ms->x = 7` is not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use:

```
vector<int>* MyStruct::vec = NULL;
```

The object type is `vector<int>*`. The object is in the scope of `MyStruct`.

---

The line

```
vector<int> MyStruct::*vec = NULL;
```

defines a global variable named `vec` that could point to a member variable of `MyStruct` of type `vector<int>`.

Given

```
MyStruct { vector<int> a; vector<int> b; };
```

You could use

```
vec = &MyStruct::a;
```

or

```
vec = &MyStruct::b;
```

As you can see, that's quite different.

Answer (score 2):

The line needs to be

```
vector<int> * MyStruct::vec = NULL;
```

Comment: don't be rude to yourself